# Value of field item in ADOOB Recordset cannot be read as string in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

1. I am trying to read some excel file without opening them with ADOODB.Connection. I have been successful with that.
2. However, some of the source Excel file that have headers (as text) in 8th row. These headers are all text and are nicely displayed when I open in MS Excel. However, when I read them with with the following code, only some of the fields are readable as TEXT, whereas rest of the fields give the following error and are simply un-readable
   [image]

```
    Dim objConnect As Object
    Dim objRecordset As Object
    Dim sql As String
    Dim pathFile as String
    
    ''' Path of Raw file
    pathFile = "C:\TEST\RAW_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx"        
    
    ''' Start Connection
    Set objConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With objConnect
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & _
            pathFile & _
            ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"";"
        .Open
    End With
    
    ''' SQL     
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

    ''' Read record    
    Set objRecordset = objConnect.Execute(sql)
    
    ''' Just jump to the 8th row
    objRecordset.MoveNext 
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    objRecordset.MoveNext
    
    ''' TEST OUTPUT
    '' The value of this field (0) is read correctly. No error.
    MsgBox (CStr(objRecordset.Fields(0).value)) 
    
    '' The value of this field (1) cannot be read. Error is shown
    MsgBox (CStr(objRecordset.Fields(1).value))

    ''' Close connection    
    objRecordset.Close
    objConnect.Close
```

3. Now, I have checked the data type and properties of the field that shows error, I am told it is a DOUBLE and FALSE.

```
    ''' The properties is given as 'FALSE'
    MsgBox (CStr(objRecordset.Properties.Item(1))) 
    ''' and the data type is '5', i.e. DOUBLE
    MsgBox (CStr(objRecordset.Fields(1).Type))
```

4. In the excel file, the field is a TEXT, and not a double. I have checked "Format Cells", and assigned it as a TEXT, but still I am getting the same error. Here is a sample of a header. THEY ARE ALL TEXT

[image]

5. The only workaround is to use VBA to open the file in Excel and read the headers and put them in a array. This is fine. But, since some of the files are very large, I would like to use ADODB to read the excel file without opening them.
6. Have anyone had the same problem? p.s. I am not allowed to change/re-format the source data.

Comment: What exactly do you have in the cells that are causing the problem?

Comment: If you have headers mixed in with your data then a SQL-based approach is not going to be your best bet.  Why not delete that row before you read the data?

Comment: @norie They are all text.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes. That is also where I am getting at. Yes. deleting the top rows and bringing the headers to the top row solves the problem. BUT, the data is with the client, and unfortunately, he does not want to change any of the source data.

Comment: Then your client needs a different approach?  You don't need to save the file after the row deletion though: you can close it without saving.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah. Yes. That will work. Didn't think about that !

Comment: Is it all files or some? If all, simply configure the read in range in the SQL statement.